# MongoEngine 0.8.3 Embedded Shard Key

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a document which is in the format:

```
{ 
 'code': {
          'one': 'asdf',
          'two': 'hjkl'
         }
}
```

`code.one` is the shard key for this document. I have a MongoEngine class for this:

```
class Code(Document):
    meta = {
            'collection': 'codes',
           }

    code = EmbeddedDocumentField(EmbeddedCodes, default=EmbeddedCodes())

class EmbeddedCodes(EmbeddedDocument):

    one = StingField(required=True)
    two = StringField()
```

When I attempt to add the `shard_key` to the Code() meta, it doesn't work. If I try:

```
'shard_key': ('code.one',)
```

I get this error when saving/updating:

```
AttributeError: 'Code' object has no attribute 'code.one'
```

If I use `code_one` I get the same problem. I took a look at the MongoEngine code behind this (document.py:325 _object_key()) and it looks like it does getattr(self, k) where `k` is each item in the `shard_key` tuple.

Is there any way to make this use an embedded shard key without modifying MongoEngine directly?

Comment: any reason for using 0.8.3 and not the latest 0.8.6?

Comment: The issue is the same in 0.8.6. Also, 0.8.6 suffers from an issue with custom user models that is preventing me from using it: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/531. I actually had to downgrade yesterday because I tried it out to see if that would solve my problem and it wound up having that issue.